# How implement regex for a textfield to allow one comma one dot at a time in Extjs

Tags: regex, extjs, extjs6.5

I am working on a textfield to make it allow only numbers with max one comma and one dot(max) at any occurrence. It can accept value like "9.8,8.6". It should not allow two or more dots or commas at a time.

I have tried below code but its not working.

```
this.regex = new RegExp('[\d,]\.?[\d,]*$');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current pattern has a lot of optional parts. It would also allow for example a single comma.

If the max is only 1 comma and 1 dot per number before or after the comma, you could make it optional:

```
^(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)(?:,(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+))*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)*` Match 0+ times a dot and 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `,\d+(?:\.\d+)` match comma, 1+ digits and optionally a dot and 1+ digits
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zWKpup/1)

Your code could look like (Note to double escape the backslashes)

```
this.regex = new RegExp('^(?:\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?|\\.\\d+)(?:,(?:\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?|\\.\\d+))*$');
```

```js
let regex = new RegExp('^(?:\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?|\\.\\d+)(?:,(?:\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?|\\.\\d+))*$');

[
  "9.8,8.6",
  "9.8",
  "8.2,9",
  "5,9",
  "9.8,8.6,1.1",
  "1,8.6",
  "9.8,8.6,1.1",
  "8,8,8",
  "9.8,8,8",
  "1,1",
  "1,1,.1,1",
].forEach(s => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + regex.test(s));
});
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, do I need to use it like this                                 
 "this.regex = new RegExp('^\d+(?:\.\d+)(?:,\d+(?:\.\d+))?$');"

Comment: @SunilBamal I have added an example of how you might use it. You have to double escape the backslashes as well.

Comment: @SunilBamal I have updated the example, it does when you use a `*` instead of a `?`

Comment: thanks @The, it fails for value "8.2,9" but working perfect for all decimal values, it can be number without decimal as well, pls suggest, even fails for "5,9"

Comment: @SunilBamal No your question is not confusing, I forgot to make the last group optional. I have updated the answer.

Comment: thanks alot @The, you saved my day.. just one change required if possible its not taking first value as dot but a value can be something like ".5,9", but i really appreciate the way you help me out, thanks alot..

Comment: @SunilBamal Do you mean like this? `^\d*(?:\.\d+)?(?:,\d*(?:\.\d+)?)*$` https://regex101.com/r/pYy4Hm/1

Comment: please help for this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57374841/how-implement-regex-for-a-textfield-to-allow-one-comma-one-space-at-a-time-in-ex

Comment: @SunilBamal You could add an optional space or match 0+ times using `*` see  `let regex = new RegExp('^(?:\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?|\\.\\d+)(?: ?, ?(?:\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?|\\.\\d+))*$');` and https://rextester.com/EWLY40601

Comment: dot is not required this time @The, also please answer there so that I can accept it ..

Comment: thanks @The this.regex = regex = new RegExp('^(?:\\d+(?:\\d+)?|\\d+)(?: ?, ?(?:\\d+(?:\\d+)?|\\d+))*$'); this is working for me you are great..