# How implement regex for a textfield to allow one comma one space at a time in Extjs

Tags: javascript, regex, extjs, javaquery

I am working on a textfield to make it allow only numbers with max one comma and one space(max) at any occurrence. It can accept value like "5,8", "5 ,8" and "5 , 8". It should not allow two or more spaces or commas at a time.

I have tried below code but its not working.

```
this.regex = new RegExp('^\\d+(?\s\\d+)?(?:,\\d*(?\s\\d+)?)*$');
```

Comment: hello @The, I have tried your regex and just replaced dot by \s but I think it needs some more changes..

Comment: `this.regex = /^\d+(?: ?(?:, ?)?\d+)*$/;` or `this.regex = /^\d+(?:\s?(?:,\s?)?\d+)*$/;` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/8w0IWM/1))

Comment: max one comma and max one space @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: There are 2 spaces in `5 , 8`

Comment: Then `/^\d+(?:(?: ,|, ?)?\d+)*$/`  or  `/^\d+(?:(?:\s,|,\s?)?\d+)*$/`? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/pd0Vlg/1).

Comment: thanks WiktorStribiżew, The fourth bird, @The can we modify new RegExp('^(?:\\d+(?:\\d+)?|\\d+)(?: ?, ?(?:\\d+(?:\\d+)?|\\d+))*$'); to make it in way so that it can accept space at last as well?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a simple solution.

In order to accept possible characters you can use `?`, which signifies exactly 0 or exactly 1 occurrence of the preceding character. For your requirement, the regex pattern:

```
^\d+\s?,\s?\d+$
```

Will allow 2 numbers (with multiple digits, if you need it) with a comma between them, with optional spaces.

See the example on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GrPFgl/1)

To implement in the line of code you shared:

```
this.regex = new RegExp('^\\d+\\s?,\\s?\\d+$');
```